# Can't properly snap in camera view through clipped object

Tags: camera, snapping, clipping

I've got the scene below in Image 1 where Cam 1 is the active camera. It's ofcourse clipping through the wall in order to get the desired view (Image 2).

The problem is that when I'm in camera view and try snapping objects to others it doesn't properly work, except for a few random spots marked in red in Image 2.

If I remove the obstructing wall, extrude the wall so the camera is "inside", use Cam 2 which is closer, or work in wireframe mode etc the snapping works just fine, so I'm guessing this is an issue with the camera clipping through the wall but the tools still thinking something is obstructing the view?

It's not the biggest of problems, but I'm curious if anyone has any ideas about settings I can change to solve this, or maybe if it's just a bug?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: At first glance I'd say, isn't Cam2 also outside and clipping? So it's probably not simply the clipping which causes problems, but I'm not sure about that - I cannot reproduce it with a clipped view. Maybe add a screenshot of your settings as well, for example is _Backface Culling_ enabled in the _Snapping_ options? A possible workaround depends on where you want to snap to, for example if you could hide the wall(s) in the viewport, they would have no influence on snapping.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Yes it is indeed also outside, which is why it feels a bit buggy to me (might be something with the distance). Backface Culling seems to make no difference.